# You have a way with words

Tags: meaning

You have a way with words.What does it mean? is this a sarcastic word? or Can I use it for someone who speaks nicely? Is there another word for someone who speaks or text clearly and effectively

Comment: It means someone who has good command over the language. They can also be cogent, eloquent, verbose, laconic, dextrous, etc.

Comment: To *[have a way with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+way+with)* someone or something is an idiom.

Answer (score 5):

In general, it is a compliment:

> Wow, that speech you gave was amazing!  You have a real way with words!

As with many phrases in English, it can be used sarcastically to mean the exact opposite.  For example, picture two guys in a bar trying to pick up on women:

> Bob:  Hey baby. You must be Jamaican, because Jamaican (you're making) me crazy!

(After she walks away from that terrible pick-up line)

> Jim:  Wow Bob, that was amazing.  I never knew you had such a way with words.

Comment: +1 for the Jamaican joke

Comment: @Daniel [There's a lot more where that came from](http://pun.me/pages/cheesy-pick-up-lines.php)  :)

Comment: Is it common, I mean is used colloquially?

Comment: It's about as common as any other English idiom. It's not old fashioned or weird if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

To have *a way with words* means to have a talent for using language in a:

> > *charming / eloquent / effective / persuasive manner*.

It is also referred to as: *the gift of the gab*.

Although the expression recognises the talent of the speaker, it can equally be used of great orators or of demagogues/rabble-rousers.

That's to say, it acknowledges the ability of the speaker to use words effectively to achieve a goal, whether for good or evil.

One way of achieving such eloquence is said to be kissing Ireland's Blarney stone, part of a castle near the city of Cork. Eloquent people are sometimes said *to have kissed the Blarney stone*.

(http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+way+with+words)
(https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-have-a-way-with-words.1540004/)
(http://www.blarneycastle.ie/pages/kiss-the-blarney-stone)